# How on earth is this out of range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, runtime-error

I try to run this little loop. I am getting an error:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
        lst[i],lst[i+1] = lst[i+1],lst[i]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/bubblesort.py", line 10, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't wrap my mind over this, what am I missing? Somebody help.

Comment: Given that you go up to the last index in the sequence, then try to access `i + 1`, why are you surprised it's out of range?

Comment: Try using `len(lst) - 1` instead of `len(lst)`

Comment: FWIW, you can use extended slice notation to swap your list items: `lst[i:i+2] = lst[i+1:i-1:-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you list has last index i, you increment it once more ....lst[i+1]

Answer (score 2):

`i` ranges all the way to `len(lst) - 1`, which is the last index in `lst`. But you add 1 more, going beyond the last index:

```
>>> lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> len(lst)
3
>>> lst[2]  # length - 1 is the last element
'baz'
>>> lst[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Limit your `range()` to length minus 1 (so the last `i` value is `len(lst) - 2)`:

```
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

Python list index starts from `0` not from `1`. For example,

```
list = ['a','b','c']
for element in list:
    print element,
    print list.index(element)
```

output

```
a 0
b 1
c 2

print len(list)
```

output

```
3
```